# Kryonet disconnects client 1 as soon as client 2 connects

Tags: android, tcp, kryonet

I've worked before with [Kryonet](https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) doing 1-to-1 communication and it worked nicely.

Now I'm doing a more 'standard' project where we'll have 1 server and several clients to connect to it.

The issue I'm having is as described in the title: client 1 connects, no problem. Then I ask for client 2 to connect and immediately client 1 disconnects. Somehow the server doesn't want to keep more than one simultaneous connection.

A couple of times we managed to have 2 connected and then whenever the 3rd connects the other drops.

Running on several different devices all ICS+ (galaxy nexus,  tab2, SGS3).

The codes I'm using are very much like the examples:

server side:

```
    server = new Server();
    ServiceData.RegisterKryo(server.getKryo());
    server.addListener(new MyServerListener());
    try {
        server.bind(ServiceData.SERVER_PORT_TCP);
        server.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException. Failed to start server. " + e.getMessage());
        MyServer.this.stopSelf();
    }
```

And then client side:

```
final String ip = intent.getExtras().getString(KEY_SERVER_IP);
listener = new MyClientListener();
client = new Client();
client.start();
ServiceData.RegisterKryo(client.getKryo());
client.addListener(listener);
try {
    client.connect(5000, ip, ServiceData.SERVER_PORT_TCP);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "IOException. Failed to start client. " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
    e.printStackTrace();
    MyClient.this.stopSelf();
}
```

the listeners at the moment are just `Log.v(TAG, "something happened);` and I've also enabled all the logs from the Kryonet library with `com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log.set(com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log.LEVEL_TRACE);` so I can see when it's connecting and when it's disconnecting.

I receive two different messages upon disconnection:

```
DEBUG: [kryonet] Connection 3 timed out.
```

and

```
DEBUG: [kryonet] Unable to read TCP from:
```

really not sure what's on here and any help will be appreciated.

**edit:**
a bit more info:
I've realised that between `INFO: [kryonet] Connection 3 connected: /192.168.0.104` and my listener receive the `connected` callback, it's taking around 9 seconds! Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

To whom might get into the same issue.

Apparently it's an Android limitation (probably imposed because it's a mobile device)

I just moved the `Server` code to a normal Java application `.jar` and let the Android clients connect to the PC and it all works fine now. Until now tested with 6 devices connected with no problems.

Comment: @ Budius can you share the source code of your application? I would like to make an application that connects to a server with 3g

Comment: hi @letroll I don't even work on that place anymore. But the code examples, etc can be found on the library website: https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/

Comment: thanks for the link, but there aren't exemple for Android only, so I had remove all swing things and replace them by the widgets equivalent. But my sample project doesn't work :(

Comment: the whole kryonet connect/send/receive part is just 15 lines of code you can copy from the 1st HTML on that site. Good luck.